# Remove Words From Mysql Dump

Tags: mysql, bash, sed, escaping

Does anybody knows how to remove this word from my SQL dump?

```
 `compression`='tokudb_zlib';
```

I tried with

```
sed 's/ `compression`='tokudb_zlib'//g'
```

nothing happens.

Comment: the problem will be the quote characters in the expression, use double quotes instead around the sed expression

Comment: not work: 's/"`compression`='tokudb_zlib'"//g'

Comment: not work: compression command not found. Did you try what you suggest?

Comment: need also to escape the \` characters : sed "s/ \\`compression\\`='tokudb_zlib'//g"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed "s/ \`compression\`='tokudb_zlib'//g"
```